# Existence of a point when partial derivatives equal $0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose the function $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has
>   continuous second-order partial derivatives, and at the origin $(0,
>  0)$, suppose
>
> $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0, 0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial
>  y}(0,0) = 0.$$
>
> Moreover, suppose for any nonzero point $h \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, we
>   have $\langle \nabla^{2}f(0,0)h, h\rangle > 0$.
>
> Use single-variable theory to prove there exists $r > 0 $ such that
>
> $$f(th) > f(0,0) $$
>
> provided that $0 < |t| < r$.

Here, $\nabla^{2} f(x)$ denotes the Hessian of $f(x)$.

I'd like to know how to solve this problem, but I'm sort of startled by all of the assumptions that the problem makes. The results of the problem make sense to me intuitively because I interpret $\langle \nabla^{2} f(0,0)h, h\rangle > 0$ to mean increasing, and we're wanting to show that the function attains a larger value.

However, I have tried this problem for a long time, and I have not been able to solve it. Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(t): =f(th)$ for $t \in \mathbb R.$

From $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0, 0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial
 y}(0,0) = 0$, we see

$$g'(0)=0.$$

Furthermore we have

$$g''(0)=\langle \nabla^{2}f(0,0)h, h\rangle > 0$$

for all $h \ne (0,0).$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: I'm still having some trouble. I don't really know how to use this information in $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ to prove the existence of a point in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: If $g'(0)=0$ and $g''(0)>0$, then $g$ has a strong local minimum at $t=0.$ Hence there is $r>0$ such that $g(t)>g(0)$ for $0<|t|<r.$ This gives $f(th) > f(0,0)$ for $0<|t|<r.$

Comment: Thanks - one question: How did you get "This gives $f(th) > f(0,0) \ldots$ in your previous comment?

Comment: $g(t)=f(th)$ and $g(0)=f(0,0).$